# I am having a difficult time reading Wireshark output

Tags: wireshark

I am new to Wireshark and I am trying to determine if the recipient of this message will use an SMTP to retrieve an e-mail from the server.

[image: Wireshark screenshot]

Comment: Look at your destination at the external addresses. That is all that is going out and that was very little. Much else was internal to your computer.

Answer (score 2):

> I am new to Wireshark and I am trying to determine if the recipient of this message will use an SMTP to retrieve an e-mail from the server.

No, the sender of this email sends the email to the recipient's email domain server via the SMTP protocol so email is sent via the SMTP protocol and not retrieved.

The recipient will use IMAP, POP3, or another protocol to retrieve this message from the mailbox on the destination email server.

You can confirm from the Wireshark trace that the email server successful sent the email to the mailbox you sent it to.

---

### Supporting Resources

- [Simple Mail Transfer Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol)
- [What is IMAP and which are the default IMAP ports](https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/email/protocols-pop3-smtp-imap/#:%7E:text=IMAP%20and%20POP3%20are%20the,simultaneous%20access%20by%20multiple%20clients.)

Comment: You can see from the trace... SYN, SYN-ACK, SYN, and then the SMTP commands, etc. The `RCPT TO` email address/mailbox existed and you send it some data. That's what I believe you can tell from there. How they retrieve it depends on how they access the email mailbox via other protocols.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a mail transaction. Remember all email transmissions are now encrypted.

I went through all the text on the side and there is nothing informative.

You would have to capture the entire email stream and then decrypt it.

[image]